# How to change the 'pin to start' icon? Windows Phone 8 app in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

When I submitted my app to the Windows Phone store, it was rejected and the report says: "The application's 'pin to start' and the 'application list' icons are generic Windows Phone icons." I have already changed the default ApplicationIcon.png to my own one. But I do not know how to change the 'pin to start' icon. The assets folder does not contain the Background.png picture. How do I have to change this 'pin to start' icon? I use Visual Studio 2012. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your tile assets. By default they should be in your Assets/Tiles folder of your windows phone project.

By default the FlipCycleTileSmall.png and FlipCycleTileMedium.png are used. So you can just replace those two png's with your own images.

For more information on windows phone tiles here would be a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662933(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, this should work:[Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-us/deda21b3-ec28-4310-96e2-a1dc11c87e18/how-do-i-set-the-application-list-icon-and-pin-to-start-icon)

Comment: This explanation is for Visual Studio 2010, wheras I am using 2012. So the properties tab looks different and has no option to change the Background.png and ApplicationIcon.png.